# Program does not tab through controls in the correct order

Tags: vb.net

I have a form with a button which adds text boxes in addition to the 8 text boxes already on the form which are named Textbox1 through 8. When I launch the application and enter the first textbox, I can tab through all the way from 1 - 8.

When I click my button it programmatically creates a textbox below the last textbox with appropriate name such as Textbox9 for the ninth, Textbox10 for the tenth etc.

However when a textbox is added via the button, tabbing through the controls skips from the eighth, to any buttons on the form, and then to the created textbox. Any idea why this happens and how I can resolve it? I've tried google to no avail. Please let me know if you need any code, thank you.

Comment: Try setting the TabIndex property for the controls.

Comment: You need to modify the TabIndex property of the new controls.  The TabIndex is the order that pressing the Tab key follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel Cook and Grim, I solved my issue by setting the tabindex to match the textbox number, however I also found that setting TabStop to false on the buttons and controls helped me to keep the tab focus within the text boxes.

Comment: I hope you're not letting other people use your app??  I can't stand it when I tab on a keyboard and it skips over buttons, etc.!!

Comment: @Grim Thanks for your comment, I realised I share your hatred but didn't give it any consideration beforehand. Now I've ensured all buttons can be tabbed through after the textboxes.